# Consider only NULL values

Tags: mysql, null

Consider below Example:-

A table with Loan and Status Column and Records in it.

```
Loan  Status
--------------
Loan1 NULL 
Loan1 Critical 
Loan1 Moderate
Loan2 NULL 
Loan3 NULL 
Loan3 Critical 
Loan4 Critical
Loan5 Moderate
```

I need to get List of `NULL` status records. As `Loan1` and `Loan3` are assigned with both `NULL` and `Critical`. So I need to exclude both the loans from my MySQL query .

Tried with Below Queries:

```
Select * from table where Status is not null ;
```

This results me with 3 records which is wrong . Can some one help me to know how can I consider for above requirement .

I did tried by self join this works, but looking for a better solution

**Updated Question:-**
How can i report total no of critical and moderate status loans.

by using max(status) i can get only  moderate records .
But if a loan has both moderate and Critical status ; Critical needs to be reported .
How can i get loan1 reported as Moderate

**output :-**

```
NULL     Critical    Moderate 
1        3             1
```

**NULL** - total loans with status NULL - loan2

**Critical** - total loans with status Critical  - loan1 , loan3,loan4

**Moderate** - total loans with status Moderate - loan5

Comment: I'd seriously question your structure and logic. Why does a loan have more than one status? And why are you flagging execution of all Loan statuses by setting one to null (null is a poor choice of flag)? Why are you using one column to define both methodology and status?

Comment: This is the Schema structure , that we are requested to use

Comment: I feel for you and your team.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you want.. please provide an expected result set and I will try and help.

Comment: TanQ@Arth, i have update the Question with output,Can u please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT SUM(t.is_null) `null`
       SUM(t.is_critical) critical
       SUM(t.is_moderate) moderate
  FROM (
  SELECT NOT SUM(status IS NOT NULL) is_null
         SUM(status='critical') AND TRUE is_critical
         SUM(status='moderate') AND NOT SUM(status = 'critical') is_moderate
    FROM table
GROUP BY loan 
       ) t
```

Comment: This worked exartly the way it should be... I got my expected result from the above Query @Arth.!! Trying to understand this...

Comment: @Surya I've tried to cover edge cases such as duplicate NULLs or criticals, but it may be worth testing these if applicable.. no problem, happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    Loan
FROM
    Loans
GROUP BY
  Loan
HAVING
    MAX(Status) IS NULL
```

Comment: This helped me , but got in to an other loop hole , i have updated my Question , can you please have a look

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table
WHERE 
    Status is not null
    AND NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            NULL
        FROM
            table AS innerTbl
        WHERE
            innerTbl.Loan  = table.Loan
            AND innerTbl.Status IS NULL
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

try it

```
select * 
  from (
    select if(a.loan in (
      select loan 
        from table 
       where status is not null
           ),null,a.loan) as loan,
           a.status 
      from (
        Select * 
          from table 
         where status is null
           ) a
       ) b 
 where b.loan is not null
```